# obtener los valores de rawX, rawY, rawZ con la api de JavaScript de del SDK 1.8 de Kinect

Tags: javascript, html5

intento obtener los alores primos de handpointer rawX sdk  de la interaccion de kinect 1.8  javascript api, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn452368.aspx, he intentado pero no me da resultados.

```
        rawX =this.rawX;
        rawY =this.rawY;
        rawZ =this.rawZ;
```

Comment: Podrias poner el código que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

lo valores de x,y,z que son arrojados por el sensor para html y javascript son a traves de un websocket que permite que el flujo de interaccion sea visto y a traves de svg la mano sea pintada sobre la pantalla, en la api la función de actualizar toma los nuevos valores de x,y,z de la mano y los vuelve a pintar en milisegundos
 this.rawx=streamHandPointer.rawx;
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí es la consola]
Esta es la consola que como es de predecible el flujo de datos y la mano se detecta mejor  en en el navegador de Microsoft